# How to use a javascript variable inside style tag for positioning a div by document.write()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a div using javascript document.write() in a specified position .

This gives correct answer

```
document.write("<div style='position: absolute; left:200px; top:100px;'<h1 style='font-size:10px; color:blue;'> HELLO WORLD<h1></div>");
```

but whenever I use a javascript variable in top and left, left gives correct position but top don't

```
document.write("<div style='position: absolute; left: " + left + "px; top: " + top + "px;'>" + "    <h1 style='font-size:10px; color:blue;'> HELLO WORLD<h1></div>");
```

How can I use a javascript variable in top?

Comment: because `top` equates to [window.top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top) which is read only ... use a different variable name, e.g. `var Top`, or enclose the code in a function, or an IIFE ... or don't use `document.write` at all

Comment: It work's. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> Because `top` equates to `window.top` which is read only ... use a
>   different variable name, or enclose the code in a function, or an IIFE.

– answered by [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x)

Comment: Now document.write() works fine. Why not to use it? I am new in javascript :)

Comment: You can get away with document.write in a simple page - but anything more complex than a very very simple page, document.write is definitely something to avoid - note: I didn't post an answer as I'm sure it's been asked before

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: no, not at all - I could be wrong :p the document.write part is not relevant to the question though (remove that from the answer :p )

Answer (score 0):

Please change your variable name `top` to some other e.g. `top2` etc.

**top** is Windoww object in JavaScript.

Here s the example that shows it.

```
var top = 100;  // not ok (it's Window Object)
var top2 = 100; // ok
var left = 200; // ok

/* top */
console.log(alert("<div style='position: absolute; left:" + top +"px; top:" + left + "px;'> <h1 style='font-size:10px; color:blue;'> HELLO WORLD </h1></div>"));
// <div style='position: absolute; left:[object Window]px; top:200px;'> <h1 style='font-size:10px; color:blue;'> HELLO WORLD </h1></div>


/* top2 */
<div style='position: absolute; left:[object Window]px; top:200px;'> <h1 style='font-size:10px; color:blue;'> HELLO WORLD </h1></div>
// <div style='position: absolute; left:100px; top:200px;'> <h1 style='font-size:10px; color:blue;'> HELLO WORLD </h1></div
```